# Using pragma Convention without export

Tags: export, ada, conventions

I need to use the Ada library from Lua. I want to use a generic package, which, along with other data, will contain a function that will register in Lua with different names depending on the data. As I understand it, I should declare this function as "with Export, Convention => C", but when instantiating several instances of such a package, the library will contain several functions with the same names and it will not compile. Is it possible in such a situation not to use "Export", but only the "Convention => C", because only a function reference is used for registration in Lua?

```
with System; use System;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

generic

   type Data is private;
   Name : String;

package P is
   
   function Call (Lua : Address) return int
     with Export, Convention => C;
      
   function Get_Name return String is (Name);
   
end P;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need `Export` if the function needs to be visible to a linker (for example, when you have C code explicitly calling this function). If you only need to pass the function via pointer into the Lua runtime, `Convention => C` on the function suffices, though you also need another `Convention => C` on the function pointer type.

Comment: If you instantiate `P` as e.g. `Q`, the corresponding linker symbol for that `Call` will be `q__call` or perhaps `_q__call`.

Comment: @SimonWright It is true that the `Export` aspect is not required to link to the function externally (it is helpful though if you do it). The point is that it is not needed if the function is passed as pointer to the Lua interpreter (which is afaik how embedding Lua works). If we assume that OP's problem centers around how their compiler generates the external name in the presence of `Export` (that is implementation-defined), the remedy would be to not specify it if it isn't needed.

Comment: If I understood correctly, without "Export" the function is still available outside the library, but its name depends on the compiler's implementation. This is true?

Comment: @АндрейГриценко Yes. `Export` primarily exists for interfacing with other languages and tells the compiler to name the exported symbol similarly to how the target language would name it. You do not need to care unless you actually link to the function from the foreign language, which is not the case if you e.g. load the Lua library.